# Resulting force using moment?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I just can't figure this out with the stresses and moments. What is the force required on the handle to get the 850N on top?

Link to album: goo.gl/FYpc0k

Comment: Hi. You will have a hard time getting a response, because A) no one in his/her right mind will follow the link and B) this feels like its your homework and C) you are supposed to show minimal effort: What did you calculate? What concepts do you think are applicable? ...

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. So what is *your* question?

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to calculate internal forces like stress and bending moment as you tried to figure out. As i understand your problem, it is a simple case of statics. Draw a FBD (free body diagram) and use equilibrium equations (Fx=0, Fy=0 and M=0). In your case, M=0 around the pivot is probably sufficient to find the force on the handle knowing the perpendicular distance from the forces to the pivot. At this point, there is no way we can figure out without knowing the dimensions and angles.